# Indirectly accessing Python instance attribute without using dot notation

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, relationship

Given a couple of simple tables in `sqlalchemy` which have a simple one to many relationship, I am trying to write a generalized function to add children to the relationship collection.  The tables look like this:

```
class StockItem(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'stock_items'

    stock_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    department = Column(String)
    images = relationship('ImageKey', backref='stock_item', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<StockItem(Stock ID:{}, Description: {}, Department: {})>'.\
            format(self.stock_id, self.description, self.department)


class ImageKey(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'image_keys'

    s3_key = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    stock_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('stock_items.stock_id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<ImageKey(AWS S3 Key: {}, Stock Item: {})>'.\
            format(self.s3_key, self.stock_id)
```

So with the given setup, I can add items to the `images` collection for a given `StockItem`:

```
item = StockItem(stock_id=42, description='Frobnistication for Foozlebars', 
                 department='Books')
image = ImageKey(s3_key='listings/images/Frob1.jpg', stock_id=42)
item.images.append(image)
```

Ok.  so far so good. In reality, my app is going to have several tables with relationships. My issue arises when I try to generalize this out to a function to handle arbitrary relationships.  Here'e what I wrote (note, `add_item()` is just a method which wraps an object construction with a `try/except` to handle `IntegrityError`'s):

```
@session_manager
def _add_collection_item(self, Parent, Child, key, collection,
                         session=None, **kwargs):
    """Add a Child object to the collection object of Parent."""
    child = self.add_item(Child, session=session, **kwargs)
    parent = session.query(Parent).get(key)
    parent.collection.append(child)  # This line obviously throws error.
    session.add(parent)
```

I call the function like:

```
db._add_collection_item(StockItem, ImageKey, 42, 'images',
                        s3_key='listings/images/Frob1.jpg',
                        stock_id=42)
```

which obviously errors because the parent table has no `collection` attribute.  Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Code\development\pyBay\demo1.py", line 25, in <module>
    stock_id=1)
  File "C:\Code\development\pyBay\pybay\database\client.py", line 67, in add_context_manager
    result = func(self, *args, session=session, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Code\development\pyBay\pybay\database\client.py", line 113, in _add_collection_item
    parent.collection.append(child)
AttributeError: 'StockItem' object has no attribute 'collection'
```

I think it would throw an error anyway since the collection name is passed as a string.

So my question, is how can I add an item to the collection by key word instead of using 'dot' notation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do:

```
  getattr(parent, collection).append(child)
```

More info

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr
- https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#getattr

Comment: worked like a charm.  I added the Python 3 link to your answer.  Hope you don't mind.